# Cannot verifiy a signature produced by Ledger in Solidity using ecrecover

Tags: solidity, signature, ecrecover

I used a smart contract to verify signatures:

```
function verify(string memory _msg, bytes memory _sig) public pure returns (address) {
    bytes memory _msgHex = bytes(_msg);
    bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n", uint2str(_msgHex.length), _msgHex));
    (bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s, uint8 _v) = splitSignature(_sig);
    address signer = ecrecover(prefixedHash, _v, _r, _s);
    return signer;
}

function splitSignature(bytes memory sig) internal pure returns (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) {
    require(sig.length == 65, "invalid signature length");
    assembly {
        r := mload(add(sig, 32))
        s := mload(add(sig, 64))
        v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
    }
}
```

The function `uint2str` body is not important. It converts for example `438` to `"438"`.

The main function `verify` returns signer address depending on message and signature values.

This works good for all signatures, but for a specific signature it returns `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` for whatever message that is given to it.

This special signature is:

`0x8ecd9d9f1ece5bd0ea1638d9a05bc194bb7536aed42fd6a09fbeb1a9479c316760ce3ff2dfbf73ad7a488e6d46988a443430a13153b26b99a83d1101d00e36bb00`

But MEW verifies this signature without any problem.

Can anyone suggest a way to verify this signature?

P.S: This signature is produced by Ledger wallet.

Comment: The problem is that ECRecover expect the v parameter to be 27 or 28 and in the signature it is 0.

Comment: Thanks. So how MEW verifies this signature correctly?

Comment: Where is a documentation about ECRecover parameters?

Comment: I had suffered similar problem with `eth.sign` the last byte is either `00` o `01`, and I had to replace it by `1B` or `1C` (I'd guess that MEW does replace it). The Yellow paper at [appendix F - signing transactions](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) says v is 27 or 28. Also check EIP 155 that changes the accepted v values depending on the network id.

Comment: @Ismael Please post your comment as an answer, so I give the bounty to your answer.

Comment: Yes I can confirm it is a bug from Ledger (working there) The fix is done and should be release in the apps soon. I'll update my comment when it is live

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that ECRecover expect the v parameter to be 27 or 28 and in the signature it is 0.

- **r**: 8ecd9d9f1ece5bd0ea1638d9a05bc194bb7536aed42fd6a09fbeb1a9479c3167
- **s**: 60ce3ff2dfbf73ad7a488e6d46988a443430a13153b26b99a83d1101d00e36bb
- **v**: 00

From [Ethereum's Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) Appendix F - *Signing Transactions*. The acceptable values for v are 27 or 28.

A solution is to replace the byte at the end of the signature: `00` by `1B` (27) or `01` by `1C` (28).

Comment: Any guess if this is a bug in Ledger?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I don't know if it is a bug or a feature. The same thing happens with eth.sign and that is documented in web3js.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2053

Answer (score 0):

If you use golang to verify ledger signatures, this repository may help you: https://github.com/storyicon/sigverify